# remove skydrive app from windows 8.1

Tags: onedrive, windows-8.1-preview

How do I remove the Skydrive app from Windows 8.1?

It seems to come pre-installed with Windows 8.1 but lately the only thing it does is crashing every 20 minutes which of course is a bit annoying.

Comment: download this .reg file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/igu8nvtgd6awm7o/WER_skyDrive.reg

and import it. When SkyDrive crashes again you get a dmp file in C:\localdumps. Zip and upload the dump.

Comment: I uploaded a dump file to http://sdrv.ms/19lLmJR (oh, the irony)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, the SkyDrive application crashes because of an failed [ASSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sb57dw4.aspx)

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************


FAULTING_IP: 
+3116dd680
00000000`00000000 ??              ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 00000000
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 0

CONTEXT:  0000000000000000 -- (.cxr 0x0;r)
rax=0000001d267aefc0 rbx=0000001d267af5a0 rcx=0000001d267aefc0
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000001d267aefc0
rip=00007ffe2f078736 rsp=0000001d267aeee0 rbp=0000001d267af5b0
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000006 r10=0000000000000000
r11=00007ffe3159f057 r12=0000000000000007 r13=00007ffe1fcc2650
r14=00007ffe1fd44300 r15=0000000000000145
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000244
kernel32!RaiseFailFastException+0xae:
00007ffe`2f078736 e8b1000000      call    kernel32!SignalStartWerSvc (00007ffe`2f0787ec)

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  SkyDrive.exe

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  skydrive.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9431.0 (debuggers(dbg).130615-1214) amd64fre

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000000000000bcc

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_APPLICATION_FAULT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00007ffe1fdeb3bb to 00007ffe2f078736

STACK_TEXT:  
kernel32!RaiseFailFastException
SyncEngine!AssertWorker
SyncEngine!SyncEngineSubscription::AssertAPIReady
SyncEngine!SyncEngineSubscription::DeleteSubscriptionIfNeeded
SyncEngine!DeleteSubscriptionsForAllDrives
SyncEngine!coreLoop
msvcrt!_callthreadstartex
msvcrt!_threadstartex
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart


               r13 : 0x00007ffe1fcc2650 :  !du "assertion"
               r14 : 0x00007ffe1fd44300 :  !du "SyncEngineSubscription::AssertAPIReady"
0x0000001d267aef08 : 0x00007ffe1fdfdd53 : SyncEngine!TraceSession::RotateLogs+0x1cf
0x0000001d267aef68 : 0x00007ffe30b47d8c : msvcrt!time64+0x14
0x0000001d267aef78 : 0x00007ffe1fcb20c8 : SyncEngine!LogEntryVerbose
0x0000001d267aef80 : 0x4431303030303030 :  !da "0000001D23F35D28"
0x0000001d267aef88 : 0x3832443533463332 :  !da "23F35D28"
0x0000001d267aef98 : 0x00007ffe1fdfdd53 : SyncEngine!TraceSession::RotateLogs+0x1cf
0x0000001d267af090 : 0x00007ffe3159f057 : ntdll!memset+0xd7
0x0000001d267af0a0 : 0x00007ffe1fcc2650 :  !du "assertion"
0x0000001d267af0a8 : 0x00007ffe1fd44300 :  !du "SyncEngineSubscription::AssertAPIReady"
0x0000001d267af0b8 : 0x00007ffe2f078736 : kernel32!RaiseFailFastException+0xae
0x0000001d267af4a0 : 0x00007ffe1fd43830 :  !du "shell\skydrive\syncengine\clientcore\syncenginesubscription.cpp"
0x0000001d267af4a8 : 0x00007ffe1fdeb3bb : SyncEngine!AssertWorker+0x2d7
0x0000001d267af4c8 : 0x00007ffe1fcb4601 : SyncEngine!EmptySyncToken+0x7c1
0x0000001d267af4e0 : 0x0000001d267af8d0 : 0x00007ffe1fd44350 :  !du ""FAILED: assert(_pServerRefreshState.get() != nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af528 : 0x00007ffe31519ef0 : ntdll!EtwpEventWriteFull+0x16c
0x0000001d267af640 : 0x004c004900410046 :  !du ""FAILED: assert(_pServerRefreshState.get() != nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af648 : 0x0020003a00440045 :  !du ""ED: assert(_pServerRefreshState.get() != nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af650 : 0x0065007300730061 :  !du ""assert(_pServerRefreshState.get() != nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af658 : 0x005f002800740072 :  !du ""rt(_pServerRefreshState.get() != nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af660 : 0x0072006500530070 :  !du ""pServerRefreshState.get() != nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af668 : 0x0052007200650076 :  !du ""verRefreshState.get() != nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af670 : 0x0065007200660065 :  !du ""efreshState.get() != nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af678 : 0x0074005300680073 :  !du ""shState.get() != nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af680 : 0x002e006500740061 :  !du ""ate.get() != nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af688 : 0x0028007400650067 :  !du ""get() != nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af690 : 0x003d002100200029 :  !du "") != nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af698 : 0x006c0075006e0020 :  !du "" nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af6a0 : 0x007200740070006c :  !du "lptr)"
0x0000001d267af848 : 0x0000001d267af970 : 0x0000001d23f6b090 :  !du "DF0423CEDAC83D28!301"
0x0000001d267af850 : 0x00007ffe20086930 : SyncEngine!g_logMutex
0x0000001d267af888 : 0x0000001d23f39988 :  dt SyncEngine!SyncEngineSubscription
0x0000001d267af898 : 0x00007ffe1ff3794b : SyncEngine!SyncEngineSubscription::AssertAPIReady+0xab
0x0000001d267af8c0 : 0x00007ffe1fd443c0 :  !du ""_pServerRefreshState.get() != nullptr""
0x0000001d267af8d0 : 0x00007ffe1fd44350 :  !du ""FAILED: assert(_pServerRefreshState.get() != nullptr)""
0x0000001d267af8e8 : 0x00007ffe1ff3773a : SyncEngine!SyncEngineSubscription::DeleteSubscriptionIfNeeded+0x12
```

This statement causes the issue:

```
assert(_pServerRefreshState.get() != nullptr)
```

So there is an issue with the connection to the server. Make sure that app can connect to the Internet.

You should also report it in the MS forums (Technet, [Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1_pr)), so that the Windows team can fix it if your PC works fine and has proper Internet Access.

Comment: Thanks for sorting it out. I have no problems connecting to the internet. I have now renamed skydrive.exe to skydrive.exe.bak and have not had crashes since.

Comment: ok, report it in the MSFT forums, so that the Developers get notified about it.

Answer (score 3):

You use a group policy to disable it.

All you need to do is to run gpedit.msc and go to the following path:

Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\SkyDrive

Enable the “Prevent the usage of SkyDrive for file storage” policy setting and wait a couple of minutes.

You won’t be able to access your SkyDrive files from the SkyDrive app. The SkyDrive node will go away from the Explorer left navigation pane and `File syncing` will stop.

You can also do the following:

1. Press Windows key + I
2. Click Change PC Settings
3. Click Skydrive
4. Click Files

Under 'Save files by default to Skydrive'

---

Drag the knob to the left to turn it off

- You can turn off additional settings under 'Sync Settings'
- If you're on an ARM device, do this first - Run services.msc, and start the Group Policy Client service.

Comment: does applying the GPO remove the skydrive.exe as well? or does it only prevent it from running?

Comment: @jao - Skydrive cannot be removed from Windows 8.1 only disabled

Comment: disabling it via GPO didn't stop it from crashing, unfortunately.

Comment: @Ramhound it can be removed. You'd have to take ownership of the file first, then you can delete it.